# Using Component in ngFor causes Error

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-components

I am trying to use a component in ngFor from this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819312/angular-2-read-more-directive/37820535) but I get an Error (Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'false'.).

The error is thrown in the onAfterViewInit function. Is there a better way to initialize the variables?

```
export class ReadMoreComponent implements AfterViewInit {

/**
 * the text that need to be put in the container 
 */
@Input()
public text: string;

/**
 * maximum height of the container in [em]  
 */
@Input()
public maxHeight: number = 4;


/**
 * set these to false to get the height of the expanded container 
 */
protected isCollapsed: boolean;
protected isCollapsable: boolean;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.doWork();
}

protected onResize(event) {
    this.doWork();
}

/**
 * collapsable only if the contents make container exceed the max height
 */
private doWork() {
    if (this.calculateContainerHeight() > this.maxHeight) {
        this.isCollapsed = true;
        this.isCollapsable = true;
    }
    else {
        this.isCollapsed = false;
        this.isCollapsable = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Calculate height of content container.
 */
private calculateContainerHeight(): number {
    let container = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    let lineHeight = parseFloat($(container).css("line-height"));
    let currentHeight = Math.ceil(container.offsetHeight / lineHeight);
    return currentHeight;
}
}
```

Here is a example [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/H6cBxC8gAfBF4fSnWwJw?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngAfterViewInit()` is called by change detection, and when change detection causes model changes, you get this error message. 
Calling change detection explicitly fixes the error:

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.doWork();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges(); 
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/EXIXfJ7IQ7dWTjWu9l8O?p=preview)

Comment: But I just typed this as well :D

Comment: sorry :-/  . . .. . .