# Angular 2 Preview Matched Snippet of Search Query with Show More Toggle

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I currently have a simple search function implemented [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-gm2vhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fread-more.component.ts) that allows you to search for courses.  Currently the user can see a preview of the description and the keywords using a [read-more component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39859181/6521206).  I would like to add the additional functionality that a user can see the context of the description or keywords their query matched.  For example, if a user queries `probability`, there will be a match in both the description and the keywords for `89A Statistics` and I would like the user to see the snippet of the first `x` characters before the match + the match + the next `x` characters that doesn't exceed the length of the string.

I am relatively new to Angular, is it possible to access the search query bound to ngModel from the main component in the read-more component?  This way I could possibly define `this.currentText` as the relevant snippet and have the `toggleView` display the entire text.

```
if (this.isCollapsed == true) {
      this.currentText = this.text.substring(0, this.maxLength) + "...";
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add it as an `@Input()` as well:

**app.component.html**

```
<read-more 
     [text]="course?.description | highlight : searchText" 
     [maxLength]="100"
     [query]="searchText"> </read-more>
```