# ellipsis (three dots) expand and collapse the text

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to make the extra text three dots (...) ellipsis and when i click the dots the text should expand and contract. But with the code used the text is only contracted but not expanding on click of dots

```
.overflow{
       display:inline-block;
       width:180px;
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow:hidden !important;
       text-overflow: ellipsis;
   }
```

HTML Code

```
 <div class="overflow" innerHTML="{{ post.review_Text | highlighter : reviewName}}"></div>
```

Comment: You will have to create a custom read more probably. See if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/39859181/4990572

Comment: please show us your html

Comment: can u explain in more extended fashion

Comment: <div class="overflow" innerHTML="{{ post.review_Text | highlighter : reviewName}}"></div>

Comment: <div [class.overflow]="isExpand" innerHTML="{{ post.review_Text | highlighter : reviewName}}" (click)="isExpandToggle()"></div>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Applying the ellipsis

#### Using Bootstrap:

If you are using Bootstrap, you can apply the `text-truncate` class to add an ellipsis to any text, like so:

```
<span id="ellipsis-ex" class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;">
    Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.
</span>
```

#### Using plain CSS:

Else, you can define the appropriate class to generate the ellipsis as you've mentioned in the question:

```
.text-truncate {
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 150px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

#### Result:

```css
.text-truncate {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<span class="text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;">
  Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.
</span>
```

## Toggling the ellipsis

#### Using plain JS:

To toggle the class using pure JS, use

```
var element = document.querySelector("ellipsis-ex");
element.classList.toggle("text-truncate");
```

You can also use the `classList.add("#ellipsis-ex")` and `classList.remove("ellipsis-ex")` functions to specifically add or remove the class

#### Angular

Reading your question, it seems like you're working with Angular therefore you can use the built-in `class` directive to toggle the class in the template itself.

```
<!-- toggleEllipses is a boolean indicating ellipsis status -->
<span id="ellipsis-ex" [class.text-truncate]="toggleEllipses" style="max-width: 150px;">
    Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.
</span>
```

#### Result:

```js
var element = document.querySelector("#ellipsis-ex");

function toggleEllipsis() {
  element.classList.toggle("text-truncate");
}
```

```css
.text-truncate {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<span id="ellipsis-ex" class="text-truncate" style="max-width: 150px;" onclick="toggleEllipsis()">
  Praeterea iter est quasdam res quas ex communi.
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer i used :

```
<div [class.overflow]="isExpand" innerHTML="{{ post.review_Text | highlighter : 
reviewName}}" (click)="isExpandToggle()"></div>
```

used the expand variable to toggle

```
isExpand:boolean=true;

isExpandToggle(){
   this.isExpand=!this.isExpand;
}
```

overFlow css class

```
.overflow{
    display:inline-block;
    width:380px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```