# How to return function name in row html in pipe and trigger it

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-pipe

I'm trying to create a read more pipe in angular, that renders custom HTML when the pipe is used.
In the custom HTML can I access method in the component by passing it in the pipe?

`readMorePipe.ts`

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'readMore'
})
export class ReadMorePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(text: string, length: number = 20, showAll: boolean = false, suffix: string = '...'): any {
    if (showAll) {
      return text;
    }
    if (text.split(" ").length > length) {
      text = text.split(" ").splice(0, length).join(" ") + suffix;
      return `<button (click)="triggerReadMore()" style="color:red;"> //trying to pass function to the component and that function defined in that component 
      ${text}
      </button>`
    }

    return text;
  }

}
```

`Test.component.ts`

```
 <span innerHTML="{{someText | readMore:3:showAll}}"></span>
```

`Test.component.ts`

```js
public showAll: boolean = false;
someText: string = "text text text text";
triggerReadMore(){
console.log("do something")
}
```

### **problems**:

- rending HTML `button`
- can we pass function name to the component somehow?(maybe use javascript)
- if there any better way please tell me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819312/angular-2-read-more-directive

Comment: I need to format the data to that pipe and base if the data formatted or not I need to render the `read more button`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not do so. The main goal of a pipe is to format data in any way you need to. If you need to render an HTML and pass a listener to it a `Component` will fit better.

Anyway you will need to pass the callback to the `Component` or `Pipe` to specify it somewhere down the road.

Answer (score 0):

try in **Test.component.html**

```
<span [outerHTML]="someText | readMore:3:'showAll'"></span>
```

**Note :** However, it is more useful to use [directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) for these operations.